# Android: transforming images and interpolation algorithm

Tags: android, image-processing

I am currently placing images over each other by drawing them on a canvas using a matrix.
The problem is: after rotating and scaling I end up with dirty/rough edges. Looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pPQJ.png

The problem is NOT that the image is low resolution, my theory is that it is related to the interpolation algorithm of the drawing engine in android.

Can anyone give me some advice here?

Comment: Have you set [`FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG) and [`ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) for your [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object?

Comment: i did set the ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG but i did not set a FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG. is this the reason?

Comment: yes, android uses linear interpolation by default that's why you are getting pixelated image. `FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG` forces it to use bilinear interpolation.

Comment: thanks!! you wanna create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: done. I've made a small mistake, nearest-neighbor interpolation is actually used by default

Comment: The anti alias flag is AFAIK only helping when drawing lines, circles, ... i.e. all those line based things that you can draw manually.

Comment: @zapl I believe ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG will also help for object edges on rotation--but not for simple scaling operations.

Comment: @MarkMcKenna Entirely possible. Bitmap scaling in step 1 benefits from filtering only, rotating and at least the jagged edges could then be anti aliased so they appear smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses [nearest-neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) by default that why you are getting pixelated image. You can force it to use [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) using `FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG`. All of the followings variants actually do the same:

```
final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

paint.setFlags(paint.getFlags() | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```